# Jquery .append .after how to format .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
<div class="item">         
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">IMG</div>
            <div class="col-md-9">TEXT</div>        
        </div>        
    </div>                    
</div>
<div class="item">         
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">IMG</div>
            <div class="col-md-9">TEXT</div>        
        </div>        
    </div>                    
</div>
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
var ws_ftr = data.ws_ftr.records;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ws_ftr));
    jQuery.each(ws_ftr, function(index, ftr) {
        jQuery('.carousel-inner').append('<div class="item">');
        jQuery('.item').append('<div class="container-fluid">');
        jQuery('.container-fluid').append('<div class="row">');
        jQuery('.row').append('<div class="col-md-3"><img src="img/features_sliding/'+ftr[3] +'" alt="feature-'+ftr[2]+'"/></div><div class="col-md-9"><h2>'+ftr[2]+'</h2>'+ftr[1]+'</div>');
```

Which gives me this, I stopped at the first major error because I believe the others will be corrected once I fix it...

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">IMAGE</div>
            <div class="col-md-9">TEXT</div>
            **<div class="col-md-3">IMG</div>
            <div class="col-md-9">TEXT</div>**
```

This should not be giving me the col-md-3 and col-md-9 for each loop, but instead should be giving me the entire item block.

I am fairly new to jQuery/javascript and am learning as I go.  Can anyone explain to me what I have done wrong and the best way to correct?  Thanks so much!

Comment: **Unrelated:** avoid this `jQuery`, use the shorthand `$` instead.

Comment: @Ele, not necessarily. Perhaps OP is using jQuery.noConflict

Comment: @Phiter ok, in that case perfect. `:)`

Comment: I don't understand what you need to do, can you be more specific? One suggestion I can give you is to close the appended divs created with jQuery

Comment: do all append in one-line and check- `jQuery('.carousel-inner').append('<div class="item"><div class="container-fluid"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-3"><img src="img/features_sliding/'+ftr[3] +'" alt="feature-'+ftr[2]+'"/></div><div class="col-md-9"><h2>'+ftr[2]+'</h2>'+ftr[1]+'</div></div></div></div>');`

Comment: I think the problem is that when you use a selector like `jQuery('.row')` it will select ALL div elements with the class row. So when your loop starts the second time, it will also append to the elements you created on the first loop... And this goes on with every `.each` iteration.

Comment: I am creating a carousel widget...  I was under the assumption that the div would close after the appends.  That is my question, I am not sure how to close those divs...

Comment: @laural4705  did you tried my solution given in the comment

Comment: Yes!! That worked perfectly!  Thank you so much!!

Comment: @laural4705  glad to help you. I have added that as a solution too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Instead of multiple `.append()` do every-thing in single `.append()`

2.Close all the div's that you started.

```
jQuery('.carousel-inner').append('<div class="item"><div class="container-fluid"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-3"><img src="img/features_sliding/'+ftr[3] +'" alt="feature-'+ftr[2]+'"/></div><div class="col-md-9"><h2>'+ftr[2]+'</h2>'+ftr[1]+'</div></div></div></div>');
```

Note- seems that non-closed divs are creating the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Just noted that in your jQuery you never closed your any of your divs. So continuing with your code it can be completed like so:

```
   var ws_ftr = data.ws_ftr.records;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(ws_ftr));
        $.each(ws_ftr, function(index, ftr) {
            $('.carousel-inner').append('<div class="item">');
            $('.item').append('<div class="container-fluid">');
            $('.container-fluid').append('<div class="row">');
            $('.row').append('<div class="col-md-3"><img src="img/features_sliding/'+ftr[3] +'" alt="feature-'+ftr[2]+'"/></div><div class="col-md-9"><h2>'+ftr[2]+'</h2>'+ftr[1]+'</div>');
            $('.container-fluid').append('</div>');
            $('.item').append('</div>');
            $('.carousel-inner').append('</div>');

);
```

I believe this can also be completed this way:

```
   var ws_ftr = data.ws_ftr.records;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(ws_ftr));
        $.each(ws_ftr, function(index, ftr) {
            $('.carousel-inner').append('<div class="item"></div>');
            $('.item').append('<div class="container-fluid"></div>');
            $('.container-fluid').append('<div class="row"></div>');
            $('.row').append('<div class="col-md-3"><img src="img/features_sliding/'+ftr[3] +'" alt="feature-'+ftr[2]+'"/></div><div class="col-md-9"><h2>'+ftr[2]+'</h2>'+ftr[1]+'</div>');
);
```